# Linux command to print out C function code

Tags: c, linux, function, gcc

Is there a linux command that would allow you to print out the C code in the GCC header file for a specific function? For example inputting strncpy and the output would be the C code held within it. Or is the code comprised of only assembly code or something? I believe I have seen such a thing before but cannot find a command easily through searching google.

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? Are you only asking for functions defined in *header* files (i.e. `#include`-d `*.h` files) which are generally `inline`? Specifically, `strncpy` is in the standard `libc` and you could study the source code of [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) or [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/); perhaps extending GCC With [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, there is no way to do that. Yes, a library linked with your `C` code could be written in assembly, or many other languages. The source code of the libraries are not needed to use them, so there is no such tool. You need to look for the sources yourself.